# Adding custom font to bbplot R package

Tags: r, ggplot2

Below is the code for one of the functions inside the bbplot package which is loosely based on R's ggplot2 package. As you can see the font they've used is Helvetica, however I was wondering if there is **any way to include  a custom font?**  I have a font in otf format download on my computer which I want to add.

```
#' Add bbc theme to ggplot chart
#'
#' This function allows you to add the bbc theme to your ggplotgraphics.
#' @keywords bbc_style
#' @export
#' @examples
#' line <- ggplot(line_df, aes(x = year, y = lifeExp)) +
#' geom_line(colour = "#007f7f", size = 1) +
#' geom_hline(yintercept = 0, size = 1, colour="#333333") +
#' bbc_style()

bbc_style <- function() {
  font <- "Helvetica"

  ggplot2::theme(

  #Text format:
  #This sets the font, size, type and colour of text for the chart's title
  plot.title = ggplot2::element_text(family=font,
                            size=28,
                            face="bold",
                            color="#222222"),
  #This sets the font, size, type and colour of text for the chart's subtitle, as well as setting a margin between the title and the subtitle
  plot.subtitle = ggplot2::element_text(family=font,
                               size=22,
                               margin=ggplot2::margin(9,0,9,0)),
  plot.caption = ggplot2::element_blank(),
  #This leaves the caption text element empty, because it is set elsewhere in the finalise plot function

  #Legend format
  #This sets the position and alignment of the legend, removes a title and backround for it and sets the requirements for any text within the legend. The legend may often need some more manual tweaking when it comes to its exact position based on the plot coordinates.
  legend.position = "top",
  legend.text.align = 0,
  legend.background = ggplot2::element_blank(),
  legend.title = ggplot2::element_blank(),
  legend.key = ggplot2::element_blank(),
  legend.text = ggplot2::element_text(family=font,
                             size=18,
                             color="#222222"),

  #Axis format
  #This sets the text font, size and colour for the axis test, as well as setting the margins and removes lines and ticks. In some cases, axis lines and axis ticks are things we would want to have in the chart - the cookbook shows examples of how to do so.
  axis.title = ggplot2::element_blank(),
  axis.text = ggplot2::element_text(family=font,
                           size=18,
                           color="#222222"),
  axis.text.x = ggplot2::element_text(margin=ggplot2::margin(5, b = 10)),
  axis.ticks = ggplot2::element_blank(),
  axis.line = ggplot2::element_blank(),

  #Grid lines
  #This removes all minor gridlines and adds major y gridlines. In many cases you will want to change this to remove y gridlines and add x gridlines. The cookbook shows you examples for doing so
  panel.grid.minor = ggplot2::element_blank(),
  panel.grid.major.y = ggplot2::element_line(color="#cbcbcb"),
  panel.grid.major.x = ggplot2::element_blank(),

  #Blank background
  #This sets the panel background as blank, removing the standard grey ggplot background colour from the plot
  panel.background = ggplot2::element_blank(),

  #Strip background (#This sets the panel background for facet-wrapped plots to white, removing the standard grey ggplot background colour and sets the title size of the facet-wrap title to font size 22)
  strip.background = ggplot2::element_rect(fill="white"),
  strip.text = ggplot2::element_text(size  = 22,  hjust = 0)
  )
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to use the [sysfonts](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sysfonts/index.html) and [showtext](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/showtext/vignettes/introduction.html) packages:

```r
library(tidyverse)

# Create a minimal reproducible dataset
library(palmerpenguins)

df <- penguins %>% 
  na.omit() %>% 
  rename("Species" = "species",
         "Weight" = "body_mass_g")

# Define bbc function
bbc_style <- function() {
  font <- "Helvetica"
  
  ggplot2::theme(
    
    #Text format:
    #This sets the font, size, type and colour of text for the chart's title
    plot.title = ggplot2::element_text(family=font,
                                       size=28,
                                       face="bold",
                                       color="#222222"),
    #This sets the font, size, type and colour of text for the chart's subtitle, as well as setting a margin between the title and the subtitle
    plot.subtitle = ggplot2::element_text(family=font,
                                          size=22,
                                          margin=ggplot2::margin(9,0,9,0)),
    plot.caption = ggplot2::element_blank(),
    #This leaves the caption text element empty, because it is set elsewhere in the finalise plot function
    
    #Legend format
    #This sets the position and alignment of the legend, removes a title and backround for it and sets the requirements for any text within the legend. The legend may often need some more manual tweaking when it comes to its exact position based on the plot coordinates.
    legend.position = "top",
    legend.text.align = 0,
    legend.background = ggplot2::element_blank(),
    legend.title = ggplot2::element_blank(),
    legend.key = ggplot2::element_blank(),
    legend.text = ggplot2::element_text(family=font,
                                        size=18,
                                        color="#222222"),
    
    #Axis format
    #This sets the text font, size and colour for the axis test, as well as setting the margins and removes lines and ticks. In some cases, axis lines and axis ticks are things we would want to have in the chart - the cookbook shows examples of how to do so.
    axis.title = ggplot2::element_blank(),
    axis.text = ggplot2::element_text(family=font,
                                      size=18,
                                      color="#222222"),
    axis.text.x = ggplot2::element_text(margin=ggplot2::margin(5, b = 10)),
    axis.ticks = ggplot2::element_blank(),
    axis.line = ggplot2::element_blank(),
    
    #Grid lines
    #This removes all minor gridlines and adds major y gridlines. In many cases you will want to change this to remove y gridlines and add x gridlines. The cookbook shows you examples for doing so
    panel.grid.minor = ggplot2::element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major.y = ggplot2::element_line(color="#cbcbcb"),
    panel.grid.major.x = ggplot2::element_blank(),
    
    #Blank background
    #This sets the panel background as blank, removing the standard grey ggplot background colour from the plot
    panel.background = ggplot2::element_blank(),
    
    #Strip background (#This sets the panel background for facet-wrapped plots to white, removing the standard grey ggplot background colour and sets the title size of the facet-wrap title to font size 22)
    strip.background = ggplot2::element_rect(fill="white"),
    strip.text = ggplot2::element_text(size  = 22,  hjust = 0)
  )
}

# Plot MRE using bbc style
ggplot(df, aes(x = Species, y = Weight, fill = Species)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  bbc_style()
```

[image]

```r
# Load packages and load chosen font
library(sysfonts)
font_add("Tristram", regular = "~/Downloads/tristram-font/Tristram-V3vl.otf")
library(showtext)
#> Loading required package: showtextdb

# Set showtext to 'auto'
showtext_auto()

# Create a new bbc style function and change the font to "Tristram"
bbc_style_diff_font <- function() {
  font <- "Tristram"
  
  ggplot2::theme(
    
    #Text format:
    #This sets the font, size, type and colour of text for the chart's title
    plot.title = ggplot2::element_text(family=font,
                                       size=28,
                                       face="bold",
                                       color="#222222"),
    #This sets the font, size, type and colour of text for the chart's subtitle, as well as setting a margin between the title and the subtitle
    plot.subtitle = ggplot2::element_text(family=font,
                                          size=22,
                                          margin=ggplot2::margin(9,0,9,0)),
    plot.caption = ggplot2::element_blank(),
    #This leaves the caption text element empty, because it is set elsewhere in the finalise plot function
    
    #Legend format
    #This sets the position and alignment of the legend, removes a title and backround for it and sets the requirements for any text within the legend. The legend may often need some more manual tweaking when it comes to its exact position based on the plot coordinates.
    legend.position = "top",
    legend.text.align = 0,
    legend.background = ggplot2::element_blank(),
    legend.title = ggplot2::element_blank(),
    legend.key = ggplot2::element_blank(),
    legend.text = ggplot2::element_text(family=font,
                                        size=18,
                                        color="#222222"),
    
    #Axis format
    #This sets the text font, size and colour for the axis test, as well as setting the margins and removes lines and ticks. In some cases, axis lines and axis ticks are things we would want to have in the chart - the cookbook shows examples of how to do so.
    axis.title = ggplot2::element_blank(),
    axis.text = ggplot2::element_text(family=font,
                                      size=18,
                                      color="#222222"),
    axis.text.x = ggplot2::element_text(margin=ggplot2::margin(5, b = 10)),
    axis.ticks = ggplot2::element_blank(),
    axis.line = ggplot2::element_blank(),
    
    #Grid lines
    #This removes all minor gridlines and adds major y gridlines. In many cases you will want to change this to remove y gridlines and add x gridlines. The cookbook shows you examples for doing so
    panel.grid.minor = ggplot2::element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major.y = ggplot2::element_line(color="#cbcbcb"),
    panel.grid.major.x = ggplot2::element_blank(),
    
    #Blank background
    #This sets the panel background as blank, removing the standard grey ggplot background colour from the plot
    panel.background = ggplot2::element_blank(),
    
    #Strip background (#This sets the panel background for facet-wrapped plots to white, removing the standard grey ggplot background colour and sets the title size of the facet-wrap title to font size 22)
    strip.background = ggplot2::element_rect(fill="white"),
    strip.text = ggplot2::element_text(size  = 22,  hjust = 0)
  )
}

# Plot the MRE
ggplot(df, aes(x = Species, y = Weight, fill = Species)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  bbc_style_diff_font()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-08-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

** I've found that changing the font may not 'work' immediately - sometimes you need to load the font and restart your R session and load it again before the system can 'see' it and use it for plotting. If you try a couple of times and it still doesn't work, perhaps some more troubleshooting will be required.

Comment: Wow! Thanks so much I tried a few time before but never got it to work but this solution works well for my package and thankfully didn't get any errors.

Answer (score 0):

Just run this to map helvetica to a different font and it will work fine:

```
windowsFonts(Helvetica = "TT Arial")
```